# NSFetchedRequestController with NSSet property as sectionNameKeyPath. Is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Let's consider I have 2 entities Product and Category with many-to-many relationship between them. I want to fill UITableView with products divided by categories.

What sectionNameKeyPath should I set to NSFetchedResultsController? Setting @"categories" of type NSSet doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have you found any solutions? I've got exactly the same problem now.

Comment: Nope bro! I ended with my own object (with interface like FetchedResultsController) which provides NSFetchedResultsController for each section.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have categoryName for attribute in your Categories Entity, I think your section keypath could be @"categories.categoryName".  Where categories is your NSSet pointing to Category Entity objects.

Comment: nope! it throws exception with reason 'to-many key not allowed here';